# Deserializing SSIS data from DTSX file

Tags: c#, serialization, ssis

I am trying to deserialize XML from SSIS DTSX files.  I have found the XSD files which I think are needed, found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg587628%28v=sql.105%29.aspx.  I have used xsd2code plugin for VS to create objects from the XSDs.

**The problem:** I am able to deserialize into these objects, but almost no actual data gets pulled in from the DTSX files.

In the code below, I have placed a break point at the WriteLine() command in Parse_XML() and looked at the contents of the two ExecutableTypePackage objects (executables and exec).  Both have the same contents:

- The property ExecutableType gets set to "SSIS.Package.3"
- The Property collection (List<ExecutableTypePackageProperty>) has one element; its Name property is set to "PackageFormatVersion" and Value property is set to "6".

That's all.  While those values are correct, there's a lot more data in the file that's not getting pulled in.  But I get no warnings nor exceptions.

Admittedly, I don't have much experience with XML, and using the serialization methods is very new to me, but I have used them for validating the XML structure of report files (RDL), and never ran across any such issues.  I have been beating my head against the wall for 2 full days on this now, and I am not making any progress.  I have searched every which way I can think of for answers on this, but I don't find anyone else having this problem.

```
    string file = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Run_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Parse_XML();
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }

    private void Parse_XML()
    {
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(file);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DTSX.ExecutableTypePackage));
        DTSX.ExecutableTypePackage executables = (DTSX.ExecutableTypePackage)serializer.Deserialize(tr);

        DTSX.ExecutableTypePackage exec = DTSX.ExecutableTypePackage.Deserialize(File.ReadAllText(file));

        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Found {0} executables in package.", exec.Executable.Count));

        Console.WriteLine("Done loading root object.");
    }

    private void File_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int text_size = -1;
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            try
            {
                string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                text_size = text.Length;
                File_txtbx.Text = file;
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(file);
        Console.WriteLine(text_size);
        Console.WriteLine(result);        
    }
```

Comment: Most likely nobody else has this problem because nobody else does this. Microsoft has already done it _for_ you. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ramoji/archive/2008/09/29/how-to-read-a-dts-package-programmatically.aspx.

Comment: Excellent.  This is actually for a coworker who does not have an account on here and I have been trying to help him out with that.  I saw those assemblies and asked him about using them, but for whatever reason he didn't want to use them.  Thanks for the link; I'll pass that along.

Comment: Remind your coworker he doesn't need to create an account to use the site. If he wants an account, it's free.

Comment: I do have this problem. I need to perform analysis from a terminal where SSIS is not available.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera - the blog entry originally linked by John Saunders has been archived; new link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ramoji/reading-dts-and-ssis-packages-programmatically